# How to Hit textbox value to that methode Using AngularTypescript

Tags: angular

Here im new to angularTypescript please Help me how to Bind TextBoxData.Like 
Here I have Two textBoxt And one Button

```
<div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtx1" />
    <br />
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtx" />
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit" ng-click="GetData()" />
</div>
```

Here how can i Bind these two textbox values in typescript Like

```
public class Employeee(Employee ee)
{
}
```

Comment: What's the actual problem you're trying to solve? Why do you want to do it in TypeScript? Usually view bindings are the best way. See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html

Comment: and ng-click is AngularJS...

Comment: please Suggest me How can i bind that two values Like Here my aim is to insert data

Comment: check the link Günther provided... ;)

Comment: ya im checking tq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular doesnt work like Angular 1. You need to change a lot to get this work. I would recommend you to go through this [link](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/NgModel-directive.html) . You can try below code

```
<div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtx1" [(ngModel)]="fname" />
      <br />
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtx" [(ngModel)]="lname" />
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit" (click)="GetData()" />
  </div>

public class Employeee(Employee ee)
{
  GetData() { console.log(this.fname +','+ thislname); }
  //you can assign this.fname = 'hello';
}
```

Comment: I gave you the link above.Click on it for more details on how to use forms

Comment: Please upvote so that others can also get benefit. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You could create an Angular component like this to create the two-way binding, using Typescript

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'a-selector',
    template:   `<div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtx1" [(ngModel)]="text1"/>
                        <br />
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtx" [(ngModel)]="text2"/>
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)="GetData()" />
                </div>`
})
export class EmployeeComponent {
    text1: string;
    text2: string;

    GetData(): void{

    }
}
```

Regards